# How to validate a parent model attributes during creation of child model's object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent model(User) with optional fields- first_name, last_name and mandatory fields- email and password. I have a child model(Booking) which 'belongs_to' to 'User' and 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :user'. My problem is, whenever the booking object is created, i need to validate the presence of first_name and last_name for the user which is being created/updated. Basically, the person needs to enter first_name and last_name when creating the booking object. I have used the 'User' model as parent at many other places but i don't want to add the validation in the 'User' model. I want the validation in the 'Booking' model.
How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use validates_associated, it will validate the associated model

```
class Booking
  belongs_to :user

  validates_associated :user
end
```

Extra Credit: http://rpheath.com/posts/412-a-better-validates-associated for getting more in your error message than "User is Invalid"

Comment: thanx for the help but this validation doesnt help me out.

Comment: thanx for the help but this validation doesnt help me out. when i add 'validates_associated :user' it gives ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `validators_on' for NilClass:Class) for the form where i m accepting the values for the 'User'.

Comment: i also tried using "accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => proc {|u| u['first_name'].blank?}" but this too doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like some code in your user class is bad. you can either post your user class (validation methods), or try removing them until you find the validator that is failing.

Comment: User{has_many :feedbacks} Feedback {belongs_to :user, accepts_nested_attributes_for :user}. User(first_name, last_name, *email, *password). Feedback(*comment). '*' field r mandatory. The feedback form accepts first_name, last_name, email & comment.

Comment: since the email n comment are compulsory ('presence => true' in model), if i dont enter them it shows me an error, but if i dont enter first_name and last_name, it still accepts the feedback. i need  the names to display the user name. in the appln, at some places i have soft-registered the user(accepted email and assigned random password), so i cant make the name fields mandatory in the user model. can i make name fields mandatory in the feedback model?